# How to show assign value in form group get from api object

Tags: angular, edit, angular-changedetection

I am working on edit functionality in angular 14. My requirments are bit diff thats why i am not using set value to assign value in form . I have get the value from api in the form of model

```
export class EditCandidateComponent implements OnInit {
  candidateData: any;
  response: any;
  editCandidateSubmitted = false;
  data = new Candidate();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private candidateService: CandidateService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCandidate(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
  }

  getCandidate(id:any)
  {
    this.candidateService.getCandidate(id).subscribe(
      (resp: Candidate) => { 
        this.setformValue(resp);
      },
      (err: any) => {
        console.log(err+'new');
      }
    );
  }
  setformValue(updateValue) {
    this.data = updateValue;
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  addCandidate = new FormGroup({
    first_name: new FormControl(this.data.first_name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(AppConstants.OnlyAlphabetic),
    ]),
    last_name: new FormControl(this.data.last_name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(AppConstants.OnlyAlphabetic),
    ]),
  });

  get candidateFormControl() {
    return this.addCandidate.controls;
  }
  
  onSubmit() {

  }
```

Here is my http call with model in return

```
return this.http.get<any>(slug, {observe: "response"}).pipe(map(
  (res) => { 
    return new Candidate(
            res.body.data['first_name'],
            res.body.data['last_name'],
            ); 
  })
);
```

I have tried set value but I am not using it because I have diff requirments. I want to show th value in formgroup. When i tried to move formgroup in setformValue function it give my error so how i can do this.

Here is the model

```
export class Candidate {
    constructor(
        public first_name : string = '',
        public last_name : string = '',
    )  {}
}
```

Comment: this.data showing api value on in the function not outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You must first initialize your form. For that, add in your ngOnInit a function like that:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
    this.getCandidate(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
}

 // ...
 
private initForm(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        first_name: new FormControl(this.data.first_name, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(AppConstants.OnlyAlphabetic),
        ]),
        last_name: new FormControl(this.data.last_name, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(AppConstants.OnlyAlphabetic),
        ]),
      });
}
```

Don't forget to declare a variable `form: FormGroup;` in your class variable member declarations.
Then you just  need to update a little bit your getCandidate function with the following changes:

```
getCandidate(id:any)
  {
    this.candidateService.getCandidate(id).subscribe(
      (resp: Candidate) => { 
        this.form.get('first_name').setValue(resp.first_name);
        this.form.get('last_name').setValue(resp.last_name);
      },
      (err: any) => {
        console.log(err+'new');
      }
    );
  }
```

You didn't post your Candidate class, but I presume it contains public attributes `first_name` and `last_name` or getter. Please adapt the names if they are not matching your Candidate class member variables.

**UPDATE**
Please try with this following logic (component/template)

Your component:

```js
export class EditCandidateComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private candidateService: CandidateService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initForm();
        this.getCandidate(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
    }

    getCandidate(id: any) {
        this.candidateService.getCandidate(id).subscribe(
          (resp: Candidate) => { 
            this.setformValue(resp);
          },
          (err: any) => {
            console.log(err+'new');
          }
        );
    }

    setformValue(response: Candidate) {
        this.form.get('first_name').setValue(response.first_name);  
        this.form.get('last_name').setValue(response.last_name);  
    }

    private initForm(): void {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            first_name: new FormControl('', [
              Validators.required,
              Validators.pattern(AppConstants.OnlyAlphabetic),
            ]),
            last_name: new FormControl('', [
              Validators.required,
              Validators.pattern(AppConstants.OnlyAlphabetic),
            ])
        });
    }
  
  // ... rest of your component ...
}
```

Your template HTML:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="first_name">
    <input formControlName="last_name">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah But I am not using this.form.get('first_name').setValue(resp.first_name); this. I just want to set the value in         first_name: new FormControl(this.data.first_name, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(AppConstants.OnlyAlphabetic),
        ]),

Comment: I have added the model I just want to know when i move formgroup in function it give me error formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

      Example:

      
  <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
  </div>

Comment: Then you formControlName is wrong because in your form group it's named "first_name". Try to change by `<input formControlName="first_name">`

Comment: And you need to define a form group "myGroup" also as a variable member and take my initForm function. Because actually "myGroup" doesn't exist in your component. So if you want to keep your logic, update your formControlName to match your control name, and create/assign your formGroup to myGroup in your component.

Comment: It give error on all input fields if i move formgroup in to function and use this.formname

Comment: Like I said in my answer, setValue will set the value at your form level, so if you connect your form to your html template by using [formGroup]="form" it will work. Basically try my answer, update your div formGroup with `<div [formGroup]="form">` and update your formControlName as well with `first_name` and it should work. You don't need this.data for this.

Comment: Very things is updated, If i not move th formgroup in any function then i am not getting any error. Sorry due the requirments i am unable to do setvalue. I have to set value in formgroup after reciving from api

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, this is what you are doing, but instead of using this.data, you are assigning directly your data to the form.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but normally the practice is to set your values at the form values, I'm not saying you can't use this.data, but it's only for "pre-defining" your values, not to set them after API call.